# Can you insert a line break in text when using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking for a way to use a line break within a tooltip text element using d3.js.

```
.text("test" +  "</br>" + "test")
```

The above, and other similar efforts, don't seem to work.

There's a thread here that seems to answer it:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/GgFTf24ltjc

but the solution isn't very clear.  How would .html be used in the above situation?

.text(.html("test" +  "" + "test"))

didn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Consider the solution I gave the link in the comment to the answer below.

Comment: The solution is different if you talk about a <text> element in an svg figure, or about any other text block (<div>, <span>, ..) outside svg. The accepted solution is for the later, see Sergei Basharov's link for the former.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16701952/837229) answer had what I was looking for.

Comment: What worked for me was to use .html (instead of .text, or .text(.html...):  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      return (
        tooltip
          .html(
              d.country +
              '<br> - population ' +
              d.population...

Answer (score 23):

Since you already know where you want to  break the text, you could consider just adding separate elements.

```
.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0em")
  .text("line 1")   // "line 1" or whatever value you want to add here.
```

And then for the second line, just add an offset

```
.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "1em") // you can vary how far apart it shows up
  .text("line 2")   // "line 2" or whatever value you want to add here.
```

Comment: Can you provide any successful example? I just follow your way and can't make any expected results.

Comment: In my condition, only line 1 can be shown, and others are disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Better to use 'tspan' for line 1 and line 2 both with attribure dy = 0em and dy = 1.2em