# How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, newline, line-breaks

So here is what I have:

```
<path class="..." onmousemove="show_tooltip(event,'very long text 
    \\\n I would like to linebreak')" onmouseout="hide_tooltip()" d="..."/>

<rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" ... />
<text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" ...>Tooltip</text>

<script>
<![CDATA[
function show_tooltip(e,text) {
    var tt = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var bg = document.getElementById('tooltip_bg');

    // set position ...

    tt.textContent=text;

    bg.setAttribute('width',tt.getBBox().width+10);
    bg.setAttribute('height',tt.getBBox().height+6);

    // set visibility ...
}
...
```

Now my very long tooltip text doesn't have a linebreak, even though if I use alert(); it shows me that the text actually DOES have two lines. (It contains a "\" though, how do I remove that one by the way?)
I can't get CDATA to work anywhere.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

This is not something that SVG 1.1 supports. SVG 1.2 does have the `textArea` element, with automatic word wrapping, but it's not implemented in all browsers. SVG 2 [does not plan on implementing `textArea`](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG2_Requirements_Input#the_textArea_element), but it does have [auto-wrapped text](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextLayoutAuto).

However, given that you already know where your linebreaks should occur, you can break your text into multiple `<tspan>`s, each with `x="0"` and `dy="1.4em"` to simulate actual lines of text. For example:

```
<g transform="translate(123 456)"><!-- replace with your target upper left corner coordinates -->
  <text x="0" y="0">
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">very long text</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">I would like to linebreak</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

Of course, since you want to do that from JavaScript, you'll have to manually create and insert each element into the DOM.

Comment: And how do I recognize where to put the `<tspan>s`?  
Replace? Split?

Comment: Tried it out  
`var tspan = document.createElement('tspan')
  tspan.setAttribute('x','0');
  tspan.setAttribute('dy','1.2em');
  tspan.textContent = text;
  tt.appendChild(tspan);`  
  
doesn't show any text at all.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why the *x='0' dy='1.2em'* is needed? It does work, indeed, just like you said. However, I was expecting it to work even without those attributes. Instead, nothing's displayed... Also, I'mnot entirely clear on **why** the linebreak occurs at all. It's not like we've set up the width of the container to something fix, so that it can impose line breaking, have we?

Comment: `x=0` is an absolute coordinate: move the text fragment to the origin of the [*current coordinate system*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace). The `transform` attribute on the `g` element defines a new current coordinate system, and assuming that the text is left-aligned, the tspan is moved to the left. This acts like a carriage return instruction.

`dy=1.2em` is a *relative* coordinate: move the text fragment by this amount, relative to the current text fragment. This acts like a line-feed instruction.

Combined, you get a CR/LF.

Comment: Not tried this yet: Could you also do this without the group?   <text x="100" y="100"><tspan x="100" y="100">very long text</tspan><tspan x="100" y="115">I would like to linebreak</tspan></text> ??

Comment: Following on from my prior comment: <text x="100" y="400"><tspan x="100" y="400">The first line of the text</tspan><tspan x="100" y="415">The second line of the text</tspan><tspan x="100" y="430">The third line of the text</tspan></text> Seems to work OK

Comment: @Richard It does work, however it has the slight disadvantage that you must compute the coordinates for each line yourself. `x=0 dy=1.2em` is much simpler, it's the same for each line, and doesn't depend on the font size. Another advantage is that if you want to move the whole text, you can just update one pair of values in the group's `transform` attribute, instead of updating the coordinates of every tspan.

Comment: Good points. Still - it's implemented now and works OK - have a goosey: https://www.facebook.com/rgraph/posts/1667831796602006

Answer (score 36):

I suppese you alredy managed to solve it, but if someone is looking for similar solution then this worked for me:

```
 g.append('svg:text')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 30)
  .attr('class', 'id')
  .append('svg:tspan')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('dy', 5)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .append('svg:tspan')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('dy', 20)
  .text(function(d) { return d.sname; })
  .append('svg:tspan')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('dy', 20)
  .text(function(d) { return d.idcode; })
```

There are 3 lines separated with linebreak.

Comment: FWIW: looks like the OP was using pure JavaScript; this answer appears to be leveraging [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Comment: I am using D3, and your approach worked for me. Thanks for posting it. I found that I needed to delete the old tspans first before appended new ones, like this: focus.selectAll("tspan").remove();

Comment: Beware with this approach that it nests the <tspan> tags since it chains .append().  This can cause some minor headaches with CSS depending on what you want to do.

Comment: See [here](http://jarrettmeyer.com/2018/06/05/svg-multiline-text-with-tspan) for an approach that avoids the nesting described by @seneyr

Comment: with modern d3 one can utilize .call() for each of the append groups to avoid nesting

Answer (score 22):

With the tspan solution, let's say you don't know in advance where to put your line breaks: you can use this nice function, that I found here:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

That automatically does line breaks for long text svg for a given width in pixel.

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")) || 0,
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 17):

use HTML instead of javascript

limitation: the SVG renderer must support HTML rendering

for example, inkscape cannot render such SVG files

```html
<html>
  <head><style> * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style></head>
  <body>
    <h1>svg foreignObject to embed html</h1>

    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 300 300"
      x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300"
    >

      <circle
        r="142" cx="150" cy="150"
        fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"
      />

      <foreignObject
        x="50" y="50" width="200" height="200"
      >
        <div
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          style="
            width: 196px; height: 196px;
            border: solid 2px #000000;
            font-size: 32px;
            overflow: auto; /* scroll */
          "
        >
          <p>this is html in svg 1</p>
          <p>this is html in svg 2</p>
          <p>this is html in svg 3</p>
          <p>this is html in svg 4</p>
        </div>
      </foreignObject>

    </svg>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I think you mean "use SVG instead of JavaScript"

Comment: It's "HTML in SVG", the best solution for me !

Comment: Mind: blown!
What's the catch?

Comment: added "limitation"

Answer (score 10):

I think this does what you want:

```
function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext){
    // Make tooltip text        
    var tooltip_text = tt.childNodes.item(1);
    var words = mouseovertext.split("\\\n");
    var max_length = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
        tooltip_text.childNodes.item(i).firstChild.data = i<words.length ?  words[i] : " ";
        length = tooltip_text.childNodes.item(i).getComputedTextLength();
        if (length > max_length) {max_length = length;}
    }

    var x = evt.clientX + 14 + max_length/2;
    var y = evt.clientY + 29;
    tt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "translate(" + x + " " + y + ")")

    // Make tooltip background
    bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width", max_length+15);
    bg.setAttributeNS(null,"height", words.length*15+6);
    bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",evt.clientX+8);
    bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",evt.clientY+14);

    // Show everything
    tt.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
    bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
}
```

It splits the text on `\\\n` and for each puts each fragment in a tspan. Then it calculates the size of the box required based on the longest length of text and the number of lines. You will also need to change the tooltip text element to contain three tspans:

```
<g id="tooltip" visibility="hidden">
    <text><tspan>x</tspan><tspan x="0" dy="15">x</tspan><tspan x="0" dy="15">x</tspan></text>
</g>
```

This assumes that you never have more than three lines. If you want more than three lines you can add more tspans and increase the length of the for loop.

Comment: Why is it `"\\\n"` rather than `"\n"`?

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted a bit the solution by @steco, switching the dependency from `d3` to `jquery` and adding the `height` of the text element as parameter

```
function wrap(text, width, height) {
  text.each(function(idx,elem) {
    var text = $(elem);
    text.attr("dy",height);
        var words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat( text.attr("dy") ),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (elem.getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution about didn't work for my case, as I needed a dynamic workaround in my React app (Especially I work on a Multilanguage app and the break lines might be  different for each language text as well).  So I used `\n` in the text where I need a break line, and then used `map` method to create multiple lines of text with `tspan` element where we have a new line.

```
const SvgComponent = ({ text }) => {
// Split the text into an array of lines based on line breaks ("\n")
const lines = text.split('\n');

return (
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    {lines.map((line, index) => (
      // Use your desired x and y coordinates and line space
      <text key={index} x="10" y={10 + index * 20}>
        <tspan>{line}</tspan>
      </text>
    ))}
  </svg>
);
};

export default SvgComponent;
```

When you pass a text with line breaks as the text prop to this component, it will render each line of text on a new line in the SVG. For example:

```
<SvgComponent text="Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3" />
```