# D3 JSON diagram text wrap

Tags: json, d3.js, text, word-wrap

I'm creating a diagram with D3 and JSON which is based on this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

In the resulting diagram, all the texts overlap as they're very long. Is there anyway to wrap the text? (text-wrap?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SVG `text` elements don't allow for automatic text wrapping or line breaks unfortunately. You basically have two options:

- Use a `tspan` element (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript)).
- Use a [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) which allows you to embed `div`s and thus specify a width and benefit from automatic wrapping.

The latter option is probably that you want. It is more powerful and easier to use. Note that it is not supported in all browsers, notably older versions of IE, though.