# How to have multiple-line annotations in Google Visualization API?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm attempting to generate an annotated LineChart using the google visualization API, and while I have it working, I would like to be able to have annotations have line-breaks if possible.  Unfortunately, it seems like Google's API ignores any newline information and displays everything on a single line.  Has anyone come up with a way around this?

Here's an example:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'});
data.addRows([
    ['April',1000, 'A', "Stolen data\nSo-so month"],
    ['May',  1170, 'B', "Coffee spill\nAnother line\nA third line"],
    ['June',  660, 'C', "Wumpus attack"]
]);
```

I've tried `\n, \\n, and <br />` and those aren't working.

Comment: The annotations do not support line breaks of any kind.

Comment: I answered my question below.  The solution is html tooltips/annotations.

Answer (score 11):

Add `p': {'html': true}}` to your tooltip like this

```
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});
```

then your add `<br/>` to your tooltip content

Comment: That's actually the answer, I don't understand why you did not get more success. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Should that with with an annotation in a view? I am trying that but it's rendering the <br/> literally.

Answer (score 9):

create a second annotation line.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Temp');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
      data.addRows([
        [[4, 56, 00], 0, '0', 'rain'],    [[5, 56, 00], 10, '10', 'drizzle'],   [[6, 56, 00], 23, '23', 'cats'],  [[7, 56, 00], 17, '17', 'partly cloudy'],   [[8, 56, 00], 18, '18', 'sunny'],  [[9, 56, 00], 9, '9', 'sunny'],  [[10, 56, 00], 11, '9', 'sunny'], ]);
```

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/k6eocgLd/4/

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a simple example for you to implement multi-line annotation using Google Chart. Copy and paste the following example and run it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', { role: 'annotation' },  'Expenses', { role: 'annotation' }],
      ['2004',  1000, 1000, 400, 400],
      ['2005',  1170,  1170, 460, 460],
      ['2006',  660,  660, 1120, 1120],
      ['2007',  1030,  1030, 540, 540]
    ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After running this code, you will see the following screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with current functionality as asgallant points out in the comments. If this is an absolute must, then you can parse through the SVG to create line breaks (which have spotty functionality as well). You can see this answer for more information on how to add line breaks in SVG:

[How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is that while it isn't possible to have multi-line annotations, you can make html tooltips and annotations: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content.  So it is possible to have multi-line annotations.

Comment: The link redirects to a different page. Could you post your solution.

Comment: I believe I linked to the correct page.  Scroll to the HTML section and you'll see how to handle it.  Unfortunately I no longer have my solution handy, but if you say isHtml: true, then you can put <br> tags in your annotation string and it will create new lines.