# d3.js how to apply text wrapping declaratively

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I inherited some bubblechart code to which I need to add text wrapping of the bubble chart labels.

How do I apply the answer here [How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript) to this scenario? I don't understand how to make d3 change the svg markup as given in the solution.

Here is my code:

```
            function renderBubbles(root) {
                var diameter = element[0].offsetWidth * .6,
                    format = d3.format(",d"),
                    color = d3.scale.category20c();

                var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                    .sort(null)
                    .size([diameter, diameter])
                    .padding(1.5);

                var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
                    .attr("width", diameter)
                    .attr("height", diameter)
                    .attr("class", "bubble");


                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                        .filter(function (d) {
                            return !d.children;
                        }))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                    })
                    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                        var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity: '0.5'});
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                        var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity: '1'});
                    })
                    .on("click", function (d) {
                        $log.debug(d);
                    })


                node.append("title")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.className + ": " + format(d.value);
                    });

                node.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", function (d) {
                        return d.r;
                    })
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return color(d.packageName);
                    })


                node.append("text")
                    .attr("dy", ".3em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3);
                    });

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
                function classes(root) {
                    var classes = [];

                    function recurse(name, node) {
                        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function (child) {
                            recurse(node.name, child);
                        });
                        else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
                    }

                    recurse(null, root);
                    return {children: classes};
                }


                d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

Here is the solution given:

```
<g transform="translate(123 456)"><!-- replace with your target upper left corner coordinates -->
  <text x="0" y="0">
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">very long text</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">I would like to linebreak</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

Comment: Here's a [d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) of applying the wrapping.

Comment: I failed to follow that but I'll work on upgrading my d3 knowledge over the w/e so I can figure it out. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try. This was a solution of Lars, it's not from myself. But it works great in my project:

```
...
yoursvg.append("text")
                    .attr('x', function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[0];
                    })
                    .attr('y', function(d){
                        return path.centroid(d)[1] + 4;
                    })
                    .each(function (d) {
                        var arr = d.properties.eventname.split(" ");
                        if (arr != undefined) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                                    .text(function(){
                                        return arr[i];
                                    )
                                    .attr("y", path.centroid(d)[1] + i*8 + 8)
                                    .attr("x", path.centroid(d)[0])
                                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. `path` is undefined and there's some screwed up syntax in the inner most .text function (unreachable code).

Comment: Sure path does not work for you because you do not seem to use a map. As you do not share a fiddle it's hard to help you more directly you know. Just replace the x and y with your own abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark thank you.

```
node.append("text")
.attr("dy", ".3em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function (d) {
    return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 2);
}).call(wrap,0)

function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function () {
            var text = d3.select(this),
                words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                lineNumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1, // ems
                y = text.attr("y")-((words.length+1)*4),
                dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```