# Cal-HeatMap - How to format date and value in subDomainText cell

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cal-heatmap

I'm trying to include both Date and Value in the same cell using [Cal-HeatMap](https://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/)

Here is a fiddle example of what I'm trying to do  ....

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/paulrollings/6L36ajhn/12/][2]
```

Any advice help greatly appreciated.  Thanks Paul

Comment: Your jsFiddle has the date and value in the cell.  Are you asking how to put them on separate lines?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to do.  Have date and then carriage return and value below all within the same cell.  Have tried date + "\r\n" + val also <br /> &013; / &#13;

Comment: I had a quick look. It seems that the text is entered as an SVG text element (in a group in the rect). Line breaks in SVG text are not fun, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript ... so I guess your hands are pretty tied. You could fork the repo or file an issue. But first I'd recommend some more research :) Good luck (\n is javascript, <br/> a html tag...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hack it in after CalHeatMap renders:

```
// wrap in timeout to let map render
setTimeout(function(){
  var t = d3.selectAll('.subdomain-text') // find all the text blocks
    .text(null); // blank them out
  t.append('tspan')
    .text(function(d){
      return new Date(d.t).getDate(); //append tspan with date
    })
    .attr('x', function(d){
      return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('x'); // steal parent x value so it stays in place
    });
  t.append('tspan')
    .text(function(d){
      return "€" + d.v; //append tspan with value
    })
    .attr('dy','1.2em')
    .attr('x', function(d){
      return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('x'); // steal parent x value so it stays in place
    });
}, 100);
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6L36ajhn/14/).

[image]