# Line break in node text in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I am using `.html(function (d) { return d.name + "<br/>"+d.label; })` to add a line break in node text, which is not working. Here is the jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/05kuwrjs/1/).

Answer (score 5):

`<br>` does [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript) work in svg. Use `tspan`:

```
.html(function (d) {
  return "<tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>" + d.name + "</tspan>" 
       + "<tspan x='0' dy='1.2em'>" +d.label + "</tspan>";
})
```

For automated line wrapping, see [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) by Mike Bostock.

Answer (score 2):

No, the *br* tag is not considered with in the *text* DOM.

You will have to use *tspan* and position it.

```
 .html(function (d) {
        var x = d3.select(this).attr("x");//get the x position of the text
        var y = d3.select(this).attr("dy");//get the y position of the text
        var t = "<tspan x="+x+" dy="+(+y+10)+">"+d.label+"</tspan>";
        return d.name + t;//appending it to the html
    }
```

Full working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4jjuuLb1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cyril, its working.

Answer (score -1):

Here i updated my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/05kuwrjs/2/), written code wrap function :  `function wordwrap2(text) {return text.split("-")}`   and using it while ierating the the node :      `.each(function(d){ 
                    if(d.label)
                    {
                        var r = d.name;
                        var s =d.label;
                         var s = d.name + "-"+d.label;
                         var lines = wordwrap2(s)
                          for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                             d3.select(this).append("tspan")
                                 .attr("dy",13)
                                 .attr("x",function(d) { 
                                      return d.children1 || d._children1 ? -10 : -10; })
                                  .text(lines[i])
                           }

                    }

            })`