# Line break in C3 generated SVG chart via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

I need a help on generating line break in html.

**Javascript**

```
var x = "jun";
var y = "2015";

var calculate= x + "<br>" + y;
```

**Html returns like below**

```
<div>jan <br> 2015</div>
```

**expected result:** i need a line break in html but should not render `<br>` tag.

**Update:** what i want is **"jan"** in first line and next line **"2015"**

I am using these values in c3 chart x values.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/602/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `<br/>`

Comment: That doesn't work. You can try it in the jsFiddle he provided.

Comment: @zer00ne, i tried but it is not giving line breaks in date.
what i want is "jan" in next line "2015"

Comment: They are using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` and even if [there are dupes](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/602/), the solutions don't seem to work anymore. So I'd say you're stuck.

Comment: if you are decided to use textContent, you can use "&nbsp;"
something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/604/

Comment: @a.u.b, no html tags are rendering. and this app is responsive so i can not use space.

Comment: @Kaiido, any cross browser suggestion.

Comment: I'm working on it but I guess the best solution would be to render an other `<tspan>` just below, by hand...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript#16701952 This answer suggests that the only way would be to create separate tspan, so you probably have to amend c3 source.

Comment: Here is a tweak, you may not like it : http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/607/ but it works

Comment: @Kaiido this sounds like a good answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question statement was a bit *unprecise* :  You are using C3.js which will produce svg element.

So the markup returned was actually `<tspan dx="0" dy=".71em" x="0">0&lt;br&gt;2014</tspan>`.

C3 will use the `textContent` property of the tspan to append the text content returned by your function.
As already said in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript#16701952), you can't add a line break into `<tspan>` elements.

So the solution is effectively to create a new tspan just under the other one, in the same `<text>` element.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get these precise elements except by looping through all others tspans, so this may sounds like a real hack but here is a script that will do what you want...

```
// get our svg doc
var svg  = document.querySelector('svg');
// get our tspans element
var tspans = svg.querySelectorAll('tspan');
// transform it to an array so the clones don't add to the list
var ts = Array.prototype.slice.call(tspans);

for(var i = 0; i<ts.length; i++){
  // get the content
  var cont = ts[i].textContent.split('\n');
  // that wasn't the good one...
  if(cont.length<2) continue;
  // create a clone
  var clone = ts[i].cloneNode(1);
  // set the text to the new line 
  clone.textContent = cont[1];
  // space it a litlle bit more
  clone.setAttribute('dy', '0.9em')
  // set the good text to the upperline
  ts[i].textContent = cont[0];
  // append our clone
  ts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(clone, ts[i].nextSibling)
};
```

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: [{
            date: '2014-01-01',
            upload: 200,
            download: 200,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-01-02',
            upload: 100,
            download: 300,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-02-01',
            upload: 300,
            download: 200,
            total: 500
        }, {
            date: '2014-02-02',
            upload: 400,
            download: 100,
            total: 500
        }],
        keys: {
            x: 'date',
            value: ['upload', 'download']
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: function (x) {
                    if (x.getDate() === 1) {
                        return x.getMonth() + '\n' + x.getFullYear();
                      
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
// get our svg doc
var svg  = document.querySelector('svg');
// get our tspans element
var tspans = svg.querySelectorAll('tspan');
// transform it to an array so the clones don't add to the list
var ts = Array.prototype.slice.call(tspans);

for(var i = 0; i<ts.length; i++){
  // get the content
  var cont = ts[i].textContent.split('\n');
  // that wasn't the good one...
  if(cont.length<2) continue;
  // create a clone
  var clone = ts[i].cloneNode(1);
  // set the text to the new line 
  clone.textContent = cont[1];
  // space it a litlle bit more
  clone.setAttribute('dy', '0.9em')
  // set the good text to the upperline
  ts[i].textContent = cont[0];
  // append our clone
  ts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(clone, ts[i].nextSibling)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new `<tspan>` for each new line. Reason is that `<tspan>` is usually found inside `<text>` element. Which has certain coordinates.
 You cannot go "against" those coordinates.

The only thing you can do is create another `<tspan>` with different set of coordinates and position it as you like.

> Because SVG Text Elements are rendered using the same rendering methods as the rest of the SVG Graphical Elements, the same coordinate
>   system, transformations, ... etc also apply.
>
> The SVG Text Element renders the first character at the initial
>   current text position.
>
> This position is defined by the 'x' and 'y' attributes of the SVG Text
>   Element.
>
> Within a `<text>` element, text and font properties and the current text
>   position can be adjusted with absolute or relative coordinate values
>   by including a `<tspan>` element.

Comment: Can you please help me in creating <tspan> for each new line.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps that's what you need:

```
var calculate= '<pre>' + x + '\n' + y + '</pre>';
```

You have to put the whole thing in pre-tags that the \n is interpreted as a line break.

About: http://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element/

Demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/gPOrEz

Comment: it is not working for the chart, sorry. i have tried it. it is rendering as "<pre>APR2015</pre>"

Comment: I think you need to create element

Answer (score -1):

i have tried following code in abc.html and it's working.please try.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
var x = "jun";
var y = "2015";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =x+"<br>"+y;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's all about c3, plain js always works. Your answer is not valid in this context.