# Trying to use chaining to create wrapped text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 and SVG and am attempting to wrap some text by using attributes and chaining. This is my current code:

```
vis.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("svg.tspan")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text("Revenue Split")
    .text("for Current Month")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
    .attr("class", "title");
```

The above is an attempt to translate this answer to using `attr`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701952/1179880

My attempt results in nothing showing on the screen.

---

update

With the help of the current two answers I've amended my code to the following:

```
vis.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
    .text("Revenue Split")
    .append("svg:tspan")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("for Current Month")
    .attr("class", "title");
```

It appears to be heading in the right direction - although not quite as expected and on two distinct lines. The text appears as follows...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the text for the `text` element and then define the text for the `tspan` element:

```
vis.append("text")
.attr("x", "0")
.attr("y", "0")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text("Revenue Split")
.append("tspan")
.attr("x", "0")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text("for Current Month")
.attr("class", "title");
```

Comment: this has helped a lot but still misbehaving - please see screenshot I've added to the original post

Comment: If you want "for current month" to be under "revenue split",  you'll have to set the `x`. value again, and probably increase that `dy`. I just edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: once this `".35em"` is adjusted to this `1.1em` things are happy.

Answer (score 2):

- You're using a . when you need a : as the d3 namespace separator for the tspan element (you get it right for the text element)
- The transform presumably applies to the text element so needs to come before the tspan creation
- The two text contents will overwrite, you can only have one per element.

Overall you probably want something like this...

```
vis.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
    .text("Revenue Split")
    .append("svg:tspan")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text("for Current Month")
    .attr("class", "title");
```

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask OP if that dot instead of colon was a typo.

Comment: (only first read the acronym `svg` last week so thanks for spotting the typo!)

Comment: @Robert - this has helped a lot but still misbehaving - please see screenshot I've added to the original post

Comment: @whytheq You've got a dy attribute and that's what it does. If you don't want that, remove it.

Comment: @RobertLongson if I comment out `.attr("dy", ".35em")` then it all appears on 1 row

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If not then explain clearly what you actually do want?

Comment: @RobertLongson isn't the title of my post explicit? `Trying to use chaining to create wrapped text`

Comment: @whytheq, you need an .attr('x', 0) on the `tspan` and to increase your `dy`.  See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQ84DWiMCHApRMJOz4ET?p=preview).

Comment: @whytheq no, it's not clear at all how you want to layout the text.

Comment: @RobertLongson apologies for not being clear - the link mark has supplied above is sport on - two lines of text, one above the other, both centre aligned

Answer (score 0):

This code by Mark in the comments above worked:

```
vis.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", "0")
      .attr("y", "0")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Revenue Split")
      .append("svg:tspan")
      .attr("dy", "1.1em")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("for Current Month")
      .attr("class", "title");
```