# Label text not parsed as svg tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have below code which parses `myObj.label` as a svg `<text>` tag.

`myObj.label = data.plan + ' ' + data.Actual;`

I would like to insert a line break in between actual and plan data. I tried below code but it does not work.

`myObj.label = data.plan + ' <tspan dy="1em"> </tspan> ' + data.Actual;`

Instead of getting a line break it just prints   when the html is created. I want to create a `<tspan>` tag in the text.

A solution is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided enough info.  What is `myObj`?  Help us to help you. Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript)

Comment: actually `myObject` is a third party object which internally parses `label` in svg `<text>`.