# How to insert line break in svg <tspan> element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have two lines of text each `<tspan>` tag for each.

```svg
<tspan dy="-11.7890625">welocme</tspan> <tspan dy="16.8" x="285.75">text</tspan>
```

Need a line break between them. but `<br>` is not working.
Can any one help me out here?

Comment: Can you provide some code here?  This is quite vague.

Comment: <tspan dy="-11.7890625">welocme</tspan>
<tspan dy="16.8" x="285.75">text</tspan>

Comment: I request you to edit the question and put the code in the question.

Comment: Pls edit the question and put the code which you have mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I think this link may help you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript

Answer (score 11):

I think this is not possible.

You can however use multiple tspan elements inside text element and use em units for dy attribute. Have in mind that there are two possible positioning attributes:

- (x & y) - set absolute position
- (dx & dy) - set relative position

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <text x="0" y="0">
    <tspan x="0" dy="1em">Hello</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="1em">World</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah...dx & dy positions adjusted to resolve issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)