# Multiple lines in HTML circle?

Tags: html, geometry, lines

I would like to write multiple lines in this circles without css, but only if it's needed style tag.

Here's the code:

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="120" stroke="red" stroke-width=4 fill="#ffffff" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1px" dy=".3em">My code<br/>isn't good</text>
</svg>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the best i was able to do. It works but its hardcoded which obviously is not ideal. I looked at this other post btw, might be of some help: [How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript)

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="120" stroke="red" stroke-width=4 fill="#ffffff" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1px" dy=".3em">

    <tspan x="50%" y="40%" dy="1.2em">very long text</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="50%" dy="1.2em">I would like to linebreak</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```