# How to change the height and width of svg <text>,if it is greater than the height and width of svg <rect> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
    <g id="newGroup" >
        <rect class="newClass" id="svg_106"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1" />
        <text class="newText" id="svg_110" style="pointer-events: inherit;" transform="matrix(0.7912 0 0 1 111.325 414.395)" x="31.5976" y="-12">This is a very long text text text text text</text>
    </g>
```

I want to adjust the text inside a rect.Some text are greater in width than the width of rect itself.I want to adjust the text so that it properly fits inside the rect.

Answer (score 2):

The `transform` on the `<text>` element complicates things a little.

What I would do is remove the transform, then measure the size of the text.  Then you can give it a new transform that scales it appropriately and positions it in the correct place.

```js
adjustText("svg_106", "svg_110");


function adjustText(rectId, textId)
{
  var rectElem = document.getElementById(rectId);
  var textElem = document.getElementById(textId);
  // Get the rectangle bounds
  var rectBBox = rectElem.getBBox();
  // Clear the text position and transform so we can measure the text bounds properly
  textElem.setAttribute("x", "0");
  textElem.setAttribute("y", "0");
  textElem.removeAttribute("transform");
  var textBBox = textElem.getBBox();
  // Calculate an adjusted position and scale for the text
  var padding = 5;  // How much horizontal padding between the text and the rectangle sides
  var scale = (rectBBox.width - 2 * padding) / textBBox.width;
  var textX = rectBBox.x + padding;
  var textY = rectBBox.y + (rectBBox.height / 2) - scale * (textBBox.y + textBBox.height / 2);
  // Add a new transform attribute to the text to position it in the new place with the new scale
  textElem.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+textX+","+textY+") scale("+scale+")");
}
```

```css
.newClass {
  fill: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 300 500 200">
  <g id="newGroup" >
    <rect class="newClass" id="svg_106"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1" />
    <text class="newText" id="svg_110" style="pointer-events: inherit;" transform="matrix(0.7912 0 0 1 111.325 414.395)" x="31.5976" y="-12">This is a very long text text text text text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This should work as long as your SVG looks like the example you posted.  If things are a bit different from that, this may not work correctly.  For example, if the `<rect>` has a `transform`, then this code will need to be modified.

Comment: Font-size of text gets too smaller.Is there a way that font-size remains constant and we can add a breakline and show the remaining text on nextline

Comment: SVG doesn't support multi-line text natively.  You would need to break the text up into separate `<text>` or `<tspan>` elements.  You would need to use some javascript code to do that. For example [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript) or a library [like this one](https://github.com/dowjones/svg-text).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this. I'm putting the text in a `<symbol>` and adapt the symbol to the size of the rect. However you may use javascript to calculate the viewBox for the `<symbol>` element.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.newClass{stroke:black; fill:none;}
text{fill:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="130 380 100 50">

  
<symbol id="test" viewBox="0 0 260 19">
  <g id="g">
        <text class="newText" id="svg_110"   dominant-baseline="hanging" >This is a very long text text text text text</text>
  </g>
  </symbol> 
<g id="newGroup" >
        <rect class="newClass" id="svg_106"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1" />
        <use xlink:href="#test" style="pointer-events: inherit;"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1"  />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

In this example I'm showing how to calculate the value for the `<symbol>` `viewBox` attribute using javascript.

```js
let bbText = svg_110.getBBox();
test.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${bbText.x}  ${bbText.y}  ${bbText.width}  ${bbText.height}`)
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.newClass{stroke:black; fill:none;}
text{fill:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="130 380 100 50">

<symbol id="test">

        <text class="newText" id="svg_110" dominant-baseline="hanging" > This is a very long text text text text text </text>

  </symbol> 
<g id="newGroup" >
        <rect class="newClass" id="svg_106"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1" />
        <use xlink:href="#test" style="pointer-events: inherit;"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1"  />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting that she/he isn't able to change the SVG but can add elements dynamically. In the next example I'm creating the `<symbol>` and the `<use>` elements dynamically. Please reed the comments in my code.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
let theText = document.querySelector("#svg_110");
let theRect = document.querySelector("#svg_106");


// create a new symbol element
let symbol = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'symbol');
symbol.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "theSymbol");
newGroup.appendChild(symbol);

// get the size of the bounding box for the text
let bbText = theText.getBBox();
// set the attribute viewBox for the symbol
symbol.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${bbText.x}  ${bbText.y}  ${bbText.width}  ${bbText.height}`)

// clone the text and append it to the symbol
let txt=theText.cloneNode(true);
symbol.appendChild(txt);

// remove the text 
theText.parentNode.removeChild(theText);


// create a use element
let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
// the use element is using the symbol
use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theSymbol');
// also is using the rect's attributes 
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', theRect.getAttribute("x"));
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', theRect.getAttribute("y"));
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', theRect.getAttribute("width"));
use.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', theRect.getAttribute("height"));


newGroup.appendChild(use);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.newClass{stroke:black; fill:none;}
text{fill:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="130 380 150 100">
   <g id="newGroup" >
        <rect class="newClass" id="svg_106"  x="133.2" y="384.5" width="76.2" height="38.1" />
        <text class="newText" id="svg_110" style="pointer-events: inherit;" x="31.5976" y="-12">This is a very long text text text text text</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: My SVG is quite big and it is of default format as above,I cant add <symbol> all i can do is to resize the text or add <tspan> dynamically if text is longer

Comment: @Shahid I've updated my answer with an extra example where I'm using JS to create the `symbol` and the `use` elements. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in JavaScript:

```
var rect = document.getElementById("svg_106");
var text = document.getElementById("svg_110");
var aRect = rect.getBoundingClientRect();
var bRect = text.getBoundingClientRect();

if (aRect.top + aRect.height) < (bRect.top)) ||
    (aRect.top > (bRect.top + bRect.height)) ||
    ((aRect.left + aRect.width) < bRect.left) ||
    (aRect.left > (bRect.left + bRect.width) {
        //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() change their values every time the scrolling position changes.So will i get the perfect value