# How to wrap a SVG's text to multiple lines using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am building a demonstration system to showcase some results of some different graph algorithms. These graphs have nodes and edges, with labels for both. Currently, my edge's labels are **overlapping** incorrectly. See my Result.js file image for an example:

[photo of my unwanted overlapping behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CabW5.png)

Alternatively, visit my system as it is currently at https://ginkgo-p.onrender.com/ . Navigate to "KG Reinforcment Learning", and enter the query "drug_delivery_device, isa" in the search bar.

Instead of the overlap above, it would be best if the edges were multiple lines (our input string can be assumed to be joined by commas - e.g. for the above image the overlapping edge label should be "produces, uses") with one line for each label when split by comma.

Currently, I have a huge Result.js file to allow for interactivity in the result.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { Text } from "@visx/text";

const Result = ({ data }) => {
  // Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
  // Released under the ISC license.
  // https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph

  const parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);

  const links = [];
  const highlightedLinks = [];

  const linkMap = new Map();
  const highlightLinkMap = new Map();

  for (const link of parsed_data.graph.links) {
    const key = `${link.source},${link.target}`;
    if (linkMap.has(key)) {
      const existing = linkMap.get(key);
      existing.labels.push(link.type);
    } else {
      linkMap.set(key, {
        source: link.source,
        target: link.target,
        labels: [link.type]
      });
    }
  }

  for (const highlightLink of parsed_data.highlighted_path) {
    const key = `${highlightLink.source},${highlightLink.target}`;

    if (highlightLinkMap.has(key)) {
      const existing = highlightLinkMap.get(key);
      existing.labels.push(highlightLink.type);
    } else {
      highlightLinkMap.set(key, {
        source: highlightLink.source,
        target: highlightLink.target,
        labels: [highlightLink.type]
      });
    }
  }

  for (const value of linkMap.values()) {
    links.push(value);
  }
  for (const link of links) {
    link.label = link.labels.join(",");
    delete link.labels; // Remove labels array
  }

  for (const value of highlightLinkMap.values()) {
    highlightedLinks.push(value);
  }
  for (const highlightedLink of highlightedLinks) {
    highlightedLink.label = highlightedLink.labels.join(",");
    delete highlightedLink.labels; // Remove labels array
  }

  console.log(links);
  console.log(highlightedLinks);

  function ForceGraph(
    status, //a string denoting status of the data
    {
      nodes, // an iterable of node objects (typically [{id}, …])
      links // an iterable of link objects (typically [{source, target}, …])
    },
    highlighted_path = {}, //a set denoting vectors (as a list) to be highlighted of the form <h, r, t>
    {
      nodeId = (d) => d.id, // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
      nodeGroup, // given d in nodes, returns an (ordinal) value for color
      nodeGroups, // an array of ordinal values representing the node groups
      nodeTitle, // given d in nodes, a title string
      edgeLabel, // link edge label
      nodeFill = "currentColor", // node stroke fill (if not using a group color encoding)
      nodeStroke = "#fff", // node stroke color
      nodeStrokeWidth = 2, // node stroke width, in pixels
      nodeStrokeOpacity = 1, // node stroke opacity
      nodeRadius = 12, // node radius, in pixels
      nodeStrength,
      linkSource = ({ source }) => source, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
      linkTarget = ({ target }) => target, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
      linkStroke = "#999", // link stroke color
      linkStrokeOpacity = 0.8, // link stroke opacity
      linkStrokeWidth = 1.5, // given d in links, returns a stroke width in pixels
      linkStrokeLinecap = "round", // link stroke linecap
      linkStrength,
      //   colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of color strings, for the node groups
      colors = ["#CBC3E3"], // an array of color strings, for the node groups
      width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
      height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
      invalidation // when this promise resolves, stop the simulation
    } = {}
  ) {
    //set highlighted path to be a set to save time
    var highlighted_path_set = new Set();
    highlighted_path.forEach((item) => {
      var forward_dir = {
        "source": item.source,
        "type": item.type,
        "target": item.target
      };
      var backward_dir = {
        "source": item.target,
        "type": item.type,
        "target": item.source
      };
      highlighted_path_set.add(JSON.stringify(forward_dir));
      highlighted_path_set.add(JSON.stringify(backward_dir));
    });

    //edit linkstrokewidth and linkstrokeopacity to highlight edges

    linkStroke = (cur_link) => {
      if (typeof linkStroke == "function") {
        return highlighted_path_set.has(JSON.stringify(cur_link))
          ? "#fceaba"
          : "#8f69a2";
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };

    linkStrokeWidth = (cur_link) => {
      if (typeof linkStrokeWidth == "function") {
        return highlighted_path_set.has(JSON.stringify(cur_link)) ? 6 : 2;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };

    linkStrokeOpacity = (cur_link) => {
      if (typeof linkStrokeOpacity == "function") {
        return highlighted_path_set.has(JSON.stringify(cur_link)) ? 0.5 : 1;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };

    // Compute values.
    const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId).map(intern);
    const LS = d3.map(links, linkSource).map(intern);
    const LT = d3.map(links, linkTarget).map(intern);
    if (nodeTitle === undefined) nodeTitle = (_, i) => N[i];
    const T = nodeTitle == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeTitle);
    const EL = edgeLabel == null ? null : d3.map(links, edgeLabel);
    const G = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeGroup).map(intern);
    const W =
      typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function"
        ? null
        : d3.map(links, linkStrokeWidth);
    const L =
      typeof linkStroke !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStroke);

    // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
    nodes = d3.map(nodes, (_, i) => ({ id: N[i] }));
    links = d3.map(links, (_, i) => ({ source: LS[i], target: LT[i] }));

    // Compute default domains.
    if (G && nodeGroups === undefined) nodeGroups = d3.sort(G);

    // Construct the scales.
    const color =
      nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.scaleOrdinal(nodeGroups, colors);

    // Construct the forces.
    const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    const forceLink = d3
      .forceLink(links)
      .id(({ index: i }) => N[i])
      .distance(320); //set how far apart nodes are here
    if (nodeStrength !== undefined)
      forceNode.strength(-5000).distanceMax(200).distanceMin(100);
    if (linkStrength !== undefined) forceLink.strength(linkStrength);

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", forceLink)
      .force("charge", forceNode)
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(nodeRadius + 2))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(0, 0)) // Add forceCenter with initial center coordinates (0, 0)
      .on("tick", ticked);

    const svg = d3
      .create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

    const outerlink = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#ab47bc")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
      .attr("stroke-width", 12)
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .join("line");

    const link = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("stroke", typeof linkStroke !== "function" ? linkStroke : null)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", linkStrokeOpacity)
      .attr(
        "stroke-width",
        typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function" ? linkStrokeWidth : null
      )
      .attr("stroke-linecap", linkStrokeLinecap)
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .join("line");

    const node = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("fill", nodeFill)
      .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
      .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth)
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes)
      .join("g")
      .call(drag(simulation));

    node.append("circle").attr("r", nodeRadius);
    node
      .append("text")
      .text(({ index: i }) => {
        return T[i];
      })
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .attr("stroke", "none")
      .attr("font-size", "20");

    const edgepaths = svg
      .selectAll(".edgepath")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "edgepath")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "edgepath" + i;
      })
      .style("pointer-events", "none");

    function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.2,
          x = text.attr("x"),
          y = text.attr("y"),
          dy = text.attr("dy") ? text.attr("dy") : 0;
        let tspan = text
          .text(null)
          .append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", dy);
        while ((word = words.pop())) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text
              .append("tspan")
              .attr("x", x)
              .attr("y", y)
              .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
              .text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    const edgelabels = svg
      .selectAll(".edgelabel")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("class", "edgelabel")
      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "edgelabel" + i;
      })
      .attr("font-size", 20)
      .attr("fill", "#9c28b0")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
        return "#edgepath" + i;
      })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .text(({ index: i }) => {
        return EL[i];
      })
      .call(wrap, 30);

    if (W) link.attr("stroke-width", ({ index: i }) => W[i]);
    if (L) link.attr("stroke", ({ index: i }) => L[i]);
    if (G) node.attr("fill", ({ index: i }) => color(G[i]));
    if (T) node.append("title").text(({ index: i }) => T[i]);
    if (EL) edgelabels.append("title").text(({ index: i }) => EL[i]);
    if (invalidation != null) invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());

    function intern(value) {
      return value !== null && typeof value === "object"
        ? value.valueOf()
        : value;
    }

    function ticked() {
      outerlink
        .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

      link
        .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

      node.attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.x} ${d.y})`);

      edgepaths.attr("d", function (d) {
        return (
          "M " +
          d.source.x +
          " " +
          d.source.y +
          " L " +
          d.target.x +
          " " +
          d.target.y
        );
      });
      edgelabels.attr("transform", function (d) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
          var bbox = this.getBBox();
          let rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
          let ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
          return "rotate(180 " + rx + " " + ry + ")";
        } else {
          return "rotate(0)";
        }
      });
    }

    function drag(simulation) {
      function dragstarted(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
      }

      function dragged(event) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
      }

      function dragended(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
      }

      return d3
        .drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
    }

    return Object.assign(svg.node(), { scales: { color } });
  }
  // Call the ForceGraph function when data changes
  var chart = ForceGraph(
    parsed_data.status,
    parsed_data.graph,
    parsed_data.highlighted_path,
    {
      nodeId: (d) => d.id,
      nodeGroup: (d) => d.group,
      nodeTitle: (d) => `${d.name}`,
      edgeLabel: (e) => `${e.type}`,
      linkStrokeWidth: (l) => Math.sqrt(l.value),
      width: 960,
      height: 600,
      invalidation: null // a promise to stop the simulation when the cell is re-run
    }
  );

  function resetSimulation() {
    if (svg.current) {
      while (svg.current.firstChild) {
        svg.current.removeChild(svg.current.firstChild);
      }

      svg.current.appendChild(
        ForceGraph(
          parsed_data.status,
          parsed_data.graph,
          parsed_data.highlighted_path,
          {
            nodeId: (d) => d.id,
            nodeGroup: (d) => d.group,
            nodeTitle: (d) => `${d.name}`,
            edgeLabel: (e) => `${e.type}`,
            linkStrokeWidth: (l) => Math.sqrt(l.value),
            width: 960,
            height: 600,
            invalidation: null // a promise to stop the simulation when the cell is re-run
          }
        )
      );
    }
    console.log("we reset the sim");
  }

  const svg = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (svg.current) {
      svg.current.appendChild(chart);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="flex-col">
        <div className="justify-center">
          <div className="group relative mx-auto overflow-hidden bg-gray-300 rounded-[16px] p-[1px] transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-indigo-500 hover:via-purple-500 hover:to-pink-500">
            <div
              className="relative rounded-[15px] text-purple-500 p-5"
              data-theme="mytheme"
            >
              <h5>Result Component</h5>
              <div className="absolute bottom-2 right-2">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => resetSimulation()}
                  className={`py-1 px-4 inline-block rounded shadow py-2 px-5 text-sm outline outline-1 outline-[#8f69a2] bg-[#fbe5a9] text-[#8f69a2]`}
                >
                  Reset
                </button>
              </div>
              <div ref={svg} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Result;
```

However, I have currently tried to make use of previous resources ([How to wrap text in SVG vertically in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767820/how-to-wrap-text-in-svg-vertically-in-d3-js)) to apply a wrap to the edgelabels code:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.2,
          x = text.attr("x"),
          y = text.attr("y"),
          dy = text.attr("dy") ? text.attr("dy") : 0;
        let tspan = text
          .text(null)
          .append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", dy);
        while ((word = words.pop())) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text
              .append("tspan")
              .attr("x", x)
              .attr("y", y)
              .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
              .text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    const edgelabels = svg
      .selectAll(".edgelabel")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("class", "edgelabel")
      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "edgelabel" + i;
      })
      .attr("font-size", 20)
      .attr("fill", "#9c28b0")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) {
        return "#edgepath" + i;
      })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .text(({ index: i }) => {
        return EL[i];
      })
      .call(wrap, 30);
```

but this doesn't seem to wrap to multiple lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Previous tricks of using , D3plus, @visx/text, React-Text or other libraries don't provide the simple functionality that I want here (to have the labels be readable, multilined if necessary, and centered).

Comment: I guess your `dy` calculation is not correct You don't need to multiply the line height with the the current line number. Try `.attr("dy",  lineHeight + dy + "em")`

Comment: As seen [here](https://ibb.co/T87L2cL), that doesn't seem to work. Is there some issue with the arrangement of the tspans? They are overlapping but I can't see why.