# Cannot add a new line in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using the recharts library to create pie charts. Here is their demo code that I am trying to modify. I am trying to put a line break under the percentage.
E.g.

> 25%
>
> Hello

Documentation: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/c9pL8k61/

This is the code snippet I am trying to work on.

```
return (
<text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'}    dominantBaseline="central">
    {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
</text>
);
```

This is what I have tried- to no avail.

```
return (
<text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'}    dominantBaseline="central">
    {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}  <br /> Hello
</text>
);
```

And this.

```
return (
<text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'}    dominantBaseline="central">
    {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}% \n Hello`}
</text>
);
```

And combinations of the above. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript helps (and in action https://jsfiddle.net/fqe9vs3c/)

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you!