# line break for d3 circle title tooltipText

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tooltip, newline

I'm using d3's svg, when the tooltipText for a circle title is "line1\nline2", the line is not broken into 2, but just **showing the raw text** "line1\nline2".

tried [Add line break within tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips) and [Can you insert a line break in text when using d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049050/can-you-insert-a-line-break-in-text-when-using-d3-js), but not working

Is there a way to have it **show 2 lines** instead of 1 line with raw text?

i.e. `\n` got interpreted. I assume changing backend response will not help since it's a bug of presentation layer.

Thanks a lot.

Trial-1, replace with "&#013" or "\u000d"

```
svgContainer.selectAll("g.node").each(function() {
 var node = d3.select(this);
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name"); // tooltipText is "line1\nline2"
 // trying to use entity code, not working. Also tried to replace with "\u000d"
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name").replace("\\n", "&#013"); 
 if (tooltipText) {
   node.select("circle").attr("title", tooltipText);
 }
```

also tried add `.attr("data-html", "true")` [Add line break to tooltip in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001766/add-line-break-to-tooltip-in-bootstrap-3/19001875#19001875)

```
svgContainer.selectAll("g.node").each(function() {
 var node = d3.select(this);
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name"); // tooltipText is "line1\nline2"
 // trying to use entity code, not working. Also tried to replace with "\u000d"
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name").replace("\\n", "&#013"); 
 if (tooltipText) {
   node.select("circle")
     .attr("data-html", "true")
     .attr("title", tooltipText);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out myself, after referencing [How to make Twitter bootstrap tooltips have multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338780/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-have-multiple-lines)

I have to change below 2 places:

1. change `\n` to be `<br />`
2. add attribute `.attr("data-html", "true")`

working version:

```
svgContainer.selectAll("g.node").each(function() {
 var node = d3.select(this);
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name");
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name").replace("\\n", "<br />"); 
 if (tooltipText) {
   node.select("circle")
     .attr("data-html", "true")
     .attr("title", tooltipText);
 }
```