# CSS equivalent to .attr("data-html", "true")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

Following up from 
[line break for d3 circle title tooltipText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646689/line-break-for-d3-circle-title-tooltiptext)

the code is

```
svgContainer.selectAll("g.node").each(function() {
 var node = d3.select(this);
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name");
 var tooltipText = node.attr("name").replace("\\n", "<br />"); 
 if (tooltipText) {
   node.select("circle")
     .attr("data-html", "true")
     .attr("title", tooltipText);
 }
```

and I'd like to replace the `.attr("data-html", "true")` function with CSS formatting

css, not-working-1:

```
# g.node circle { data-html: true;}
```

css, not-working-2:

```
# g.node circle { html: true;}
```

both above 2 have "Unknown property name" error.

I'm wondering, what is the CSS equivalent to `.attr("data-html", "true")`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `data-html` is an attribute, not CSS property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS is (designed for) a simple mechanism for adding style to an HTML document.

The code you referred to actually mutates the DOM (in this case, the html-node).

On a side note: If you want to 'select' based upon that state in CSS, you could do.

```
html {
  background: red;
}

html[data-something=true] {
  background: green;
}
```

if then the JavaScript sets `$('html').attr('data-something', 'true');` your CSS would be applied (from red background to green).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have equivalent `CSS` property. `CSS` is the look and some behavior. `data-html` is an `HTML5` styled attribute, which is used to store a data. You can add anything with `data-` prefix.

So you need to use a `Javascript` to add an `HTML5` attribute.