# How do I force line break in donut chart label?

Tags: vuejs2, c3.js

I'm using C3 donut chart,

[image]

But the label is too long and I need a `word-break` like feature.

So I tried to set the following properties, non of them works

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      width: 100
    }
  }
},
legend: {
  maxWidth: 100px;
},
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The tooltip.format.name function can partially solve this problem. But I'm unable to add newline here, tried `"\n"`, `<br/>` and `&#13;`

```
    tooltip: {
      format: {
        name: function (name, ratio, id, index) { 
          if (name.length > 70) {
            return name.substr(0, 70) + ' &#013; ...'
          } else {
            return name
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [line break for d3 circle title tooltipText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646689/line-break-for-d3-circle-title-tooltiptext)

Comment: You could use the C3  [donut: {  width: nnn }](https://c3js.org/reference.html#donut-width) option to make the donut ring wider to accommodate your text.